# pyenv installation: 3.6.6 BUILD FAILED (Linuxmint 21.2 using python-build 2.3.32)

Tags: python, linux, linux-mint

The attempt to install the Python 3.6.6 version on Linux Mint 21.2 fails with this error

```
pericle@pericle-mint:~$ pyenv install 3.6.6
Downloading Python-3.6.6.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.6/Python-3.6.6.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.6.6...

BUILD FAILED (Linuxmint 21.2 using python-build 2.3.32)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20231112214137.4986
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20231112214137.4986.log

Last 10 log lines:
if test "xupgrade" != "xno"  ; then \
    case upgrade in \
        upgrade) ensurepip="--upgrade" ;; \
        install|*) ensurepip="" ;; \
    esac; \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/python-build.20231112214137.4986/Python-3.6.6 ./python -E -m ensurepip \
        $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
make: *** [Makefile:1103: install] Errore 139
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: I solved it by reading another message by installing
$ sudo apt install clang -y
$ CC=clang pyenv install 3.6.9

Comment: Why do you need Python 3.6 anyway? It's way past EOL...